# "Il più e il peggio": si tratta di un modo di dire?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, sentences

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> I contadini ascoltavano sbalorditi. Perché mai – si chiedevano – questo nuovo cappellano non si limita a minacciarci l’Inferno nell’altra vita, come tutti i preti, lasciandoci poi liberi di fare in questo mondo quello che vogliamo? Inferno o Paradiso, sono fatti nostri; ma non sapevano, i tapini, che **il più e il peggio** ancora dovevano arrivare.

La mia domanda è su questa espressione,  "il più e il peggio", che appare in questo brano? Si tratta di un modo di dire? Ho cercato su Internet, ma non ho trovato nessuna informazione a riguardo.

Comment: No, non è un modo di dire, ma solo un'espressione sintetica ed efficace.

Comment: “Il peggio deve ancora arrivare” è piuttosto comune. Qui l'autore aggiunge un quasi pleonastico “più” (entrambi avverbi usati come sostantivi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non si tratta di un comune modo di dire, ma ***[più e peggio](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%3B%2Cc0)***  è una frase che viene usata per indicare che c’è da aspettarsi dell’altro in senso negativo.

“Il più e il peggio” ovviamente suggerisce lo stesso concetto.

Alcuni esempi:

Da [Sette](https://books.google.it/books?id=Q-s7AQAAIAAJ&q=%22pi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%22&dq=%22pi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd6unQ9MPXAhXJVhQKHeL7DigQ6AEIPDAF) settimanale del Corriere della Sera:

> È la prova che il malessere siciliano non è finito, che sta cambiando sì, ma che la mafiologia e la sicilianologia annaspano ***più e peggio della mafia.***

Da 
[Il diritto ecclesiastico e rassegna di diritto matrimoniale](https://books.google.it/books?id=kKBCf2M5MmIC&q=%22pi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%22&dq=%22pi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ6ICh9cPXAhWFVhoKHRGsCWMQ6AEIPzAG):

> ... e vertiginosa che ai tempi nostri trattiene e travolge la gioventù, e non essa sola, in cose tutte esteriori e materiali: e ***ancora più e peggio da questo generale dilagare di una immoralità***.

Comment: La tua opinione vale la mia, per carità, ma a me sembra un normale accostamento di due parole che si complementano bene insieme, più che una frase fatta, come [molti altri binomi possibili](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pi%C3%B9+e+peggio%2Clibri+e+quaderni%2Crosso+e+blu%2Cmeno+e+meglio%2Cverde+e+viola&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpi%C3%B9%20e%20peggio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clibri%20e%20quaderni%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crosso%20e%20blu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeno%20e%20meglio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverde%20e%20viola%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @DaG - non mi sembra di avere detto che si tratta di una “frase fatta”. È comunque un’espressione usata e che sento usare.

Comment: @Gio: Potresti aggiungere questo al tuo post? Così penso che la risposta alla domanda che ho fatto sarà più chiara.